# Problema com código HTML no envio do e-mail usando ACBrMail

Tags: delphi, envio-de-email, utf-8

Estou usando o ACBrMail para envio de um Html padrão que está hospedado na Web. Eu pego o código fonte do Html pelo UTF8ToString(idHTTP.Get()) e substituo as tags necessárias para envio com StringReplace().

```
HtmlPadrao := UTF8ToString(FIdHTTP.Get('http://remy.corework.com.br/mail/mail01.html'));
HtmlPadrao := StringReplace(HtmlPadrao, 'images/', 'http://remy.corework.com.br/mail/images/', [rfReplaceAll]);
HtmlPadrao := StringReplace(HtmlPadrao, '<nome da="" pessoa="">', '&nbsp;'+NomeCliente, [rfReplaceAll]);
HtmlPadrao := StringReplace(HtmlPadrao, '&lt;N??MERO DA COMPRA&gt;', NumeroCompra, [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Porém, estou com problemas com Ú (u maiúsculo com acento), ele fica assim no e-mail enviado:

N??MERO DA COMPRA

D??VIDAS?!

Tentei substituir a palavra "N??MERO" porém não funcionou. Fiz um SaveToFile para verificar e no texto, está como N??. Porém não consigo substituir para mostrar o Html correto.

Preciso substituir o código html '<N??MERO DA COMPRA>' pelo número da compra (Ex.: 42)

Como resolver? E porque isso acontece?

Answer (score -1):

É necessário substituir a String da forma que o site retorna, tente este StringReplace:

```
HtmlPadrao := StringReplace(HtmlPadrao, '&lt;N&uacute;mero da Compra&gt;', NumeroCompra, [rfReplaceAll]);
```